# Limiting execution time in Java without threading

Tags: java, timeout

(Please don't mark this duplicate as my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23649717/how-to-limit-method-execution-time-in-java-without-threads), they aren't - I am looking for a *singlethreaded* solution).

I need a simple way to limit execution time of some method in java.

Ideally I think what could be done:

1. I called a function or method
2. If a given time passes without its return,
3. it had got an exception.

But any other solution were o.k. for me. What I need, is practically the equivavlent of the `alarm()` libc call on unixes. Is it possible?

I need a single-thread solution. Multithread solutions were trivial.

Comment: You're out of luck. It would only be possible if you poll manually whether timeout has occurred, and that's possible only if your task is divided to small enough steps. What's wrong with a multithreaded solution, i.e. do you actually have a problem you're trying to solve, or are you just asking this as a "can we do this?" question?

Comment: @Kayaman Threads are handled by an outer entity here, which doesn't know anything about my intentions.

Comment: It's still better to present the actual problem instead of an attempt at a solution. Otherwise you might end up with a stupid solution to a problem that could be solved elegantly.

Comment: @Kayaman Our views differs on the "elegant solution". For me, throwing alarmed exceptions is the elegant, and not such hard boy as creating new threads if I only need a timeouted exception. And the last thing which I wanted to have a pointless debate about that I should use threads.

Comment: But Java doesn't have those. So your elegant solution is not a solution, it's a hallucination.

Comment: @Kayaman Yes, you have right on the first part: simple and beautiful solution don't exist, because in the standard java api libs was the `timeout()` (or the equivalent OS api call) somehow not mapped. There is no clarification, it simply wasn't. But the possibility exists, and calling trivial things as hallucination because they simply weren't implemented in our mostloved language/library - IMHO it isn't the right direction to learn new things out of our current viewpoint.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `timeout()` call and whether it exists for all platforms that Java wishes to support, or if it was left out for other reasons. But if you have a problem, you should state what you want to happen and why, then a proper solution can be sought out. It's useless to say that in C++ or another platform this could be solved in way X, because you're on Java and you'll play with Java's rules. If you want `timeout()`, don't use Java and whine about the lack of it. Jeez.

Comment: @Kayaman The standard java library calls are practically a java mapping around the actual OS functionality. I don't have the possibility to ignore Java, all alternatives were much-much worser. So I will solve that with threads, and whine here for you, there is no another possibility.

Comment: I was only giving you advice on how to get good solutions. You had already decided on what's a good solution, but you have no idea if there could be a better one, since you didn't describe your actual problem. You're the one who's at loss here.

Comment: @Kayaman No, I described my actual problem: I tried to make hard timeouted java api calls. And I finally got my answer: in Java it is impossible. And later I found out, that it is impossible even with threads: because they can only be stopped if they are wanted to. So, I have a trivial problem, which hasn't a working solution because in case of Java can't the trivial problems often be solved.

Comment: Fair enough, you did mention that in your description. However, it's hard to know whether the question that was asked is actually the correct question to ask. Many questions here don't address the correct issue (such as "what's the fastest collection"), and just answering the question outright isn't actually fruitful to the asker. As an example this recent question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653036/does-mysql-last-insert-id-work-for-connection-pool/23653216

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java everything runs in a thread. In order to check whether some thread is struck or not, you need to monitor it from "another" thread. Either you will need to spawn new thread by using `TimerTask`, or you some api methods like `ScheduledExecutorService`

So IMHO, it is tough to provide an elegant solution without multithreading.

There could be hacks offcourse, like the one I have shown below. But neither they are elegant nor recommended in real scenarios.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long startMilli = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for(int i=0;;i++) {
            //Do something
            long timepassed = System.currentTimeMillis() -startMilli;
            if(timepassed==1000) {
                throw new RuntimeException("taking too long");
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: I cleared exactly that I am looking for a solution without opening new threads. Your suggestion works only if you can organise your code execution as handling callbacks from a loop.