# Does mysql last_insert_id() work for connection pool?

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, connection-pooling

I have a auto increment column of type bigint. Calling mysql_insert_id() works good for getting the previously inserted id for the connection. Does it work great(identifying the last inserted id) even if a connection pool in a tomcat container is used ?

Comment: A connection obtained from a pool is yours until you call `close()`, other than that it was obtained from a pool it works (or: should work) the same as a 'normal' connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use database specific code like that, it'll only make your code less portable. Instead use the `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` option when executing an update.

Here's a start to your searches: [sql jdbc getgeneratedkeys returns column "id" not found, column type unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2854774/sql-jdbc-getgeneratedkeys-returns-column-id-not-found-column-type-unknown)

Comment: does getGeneratedKeys return the last key for the current connection ? Are concurrency issues handled by implementation ?

Comment: It returns the generated keys for the last statement executed, at the same time. Surely you'll want to fetch them at the time they're generated instead of a later time?

Comment: Yeah. I wanted to know if getting the keys during the insert is in the atomic part of transaction.

Comment: Of course. It would be quite useless if you couldn't trust that the generated keys were actually the ones in the database.